# some problems about ractivejs bind a nested array

Tags: ractivejs

The demo is http://jsfiddle.net/84xp4jan/1/ ,a nested array bind a template,when i click"Add Tab",and then click "Add Item",it not work,why?If the "arr" does not add or delete operation,the "Add Item" work good!

Comment: Please include all relevant code in your post and **don't** just include a link to a code hosting site. Your post should stand alone from any other resource; consider what would happen if that site went down in the future!

Answer (score 0):

the answer is here https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues/1850 ,the most important point is "ractive.update()".